# I need to count weekends and weekdays in a column (excluding same dates)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is for my own personal finance. I need to count numbers of maintenances done in weekends and weekdays.

I get 18€ extra for each day in weekends and 13€ extra for each day in weekdays.

I have a table as so

[image]

I would like to have a cell in a different part of the spreadsheet, lets say T14 that does that for me.

Its usual that I have some repeated days, so I would need to account for that.

In my example, I'd get 13+18+18.

I've found a way of counting dates ignoring repeated values and blank values

```
=SUMAPRODUCTO((L4:L300<>"")/CONTAR.SI(L4:L300;L4:L300&""))
```

And another that swaps those dates in (DD/MM/AAAA) to numeric from 1 to 7, being 6 for Saturdays and 7 for Sundays, but I haven't found a way of merging those two so I can count Saturdays and Sundays without repeated values and blanks, multiplying that by 18 and then adding the same for Weekdays.

**SOLVED**
Okay, I found a way of doing it.

```
=SI(Y(L11="";(CONTAR.SI($L$4:L10;L10)=1)=VERDADERO);SI(L10="";"";ELEGIR(DIASEM(L10;2);13;13;13;13;13;18;18));SI(CONTAR.SI($L$4:L10;L10)=1;ELEGIR(DIASEM(L10;2);13;13;13;13;13;18;18);""))
```

Thank you a lot!

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kllbu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this in a new sheet:

| Mantenimiento extra |  |
| --- | --- |
| Fecha | Extra |
| 45272 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A3,A3)=1,CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A3,2),13,13,13,13,13,18,18),"") |
| 45276 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A4,A4)=1,CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A4,2),13,13,13,13,13,18,18),"") |
| 45277 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A5,A5)=1,CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A5,2),13,13,13,13,13,18,18),"") |
| 45277 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A6,A6)=1,CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A6,2),13,13,13,13,13,18,18),"") |
| 45277 | =IF(COUNTIF($A$3:A7,A7)=1,CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A7,2),13,13,13,13,13,18,18),"") |

Comment: That has kinda worked. I had to edit a little bit. The only problem I'm having is with the last cell. If it doesn't have any maintenance after the last one, it should choose either 13 or 18. Atm it leaves it in blank

Comment: Okay, I changed the formula a little bit and found a solution.
I have dates on D3 on the test

=SI(D3="";ELEGIR(DIASEM(D2;2);13;13;13;13;13;18;18);SI(CONTAR.SI($D2:D$3;D2)=1;ELEGIR(DIASEM(D2;2);13;13;13;13;13;18;18);""))

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate any version restrictions, so you could use this formula to obtain your answer
I believe you need Excel 2019 for the `FILTER` function and 2021 for the the `UNIQUE` function.

```
=SUM((WEEKDAY(UNIQUE(FILTER(L4:L300, L4:L300 <> "")), 3) >= 5) * 5 + 13)
```

or, if the Excel translator is correct:

```
=SUMA((DIASEM(UNIQUE(FILTER(L4:L300;L4:L300<>""));3)>=5)*5+13)
```

If you have Excel 2019, the following should work:

- Enter this formula in `M4` and fill down to `M300`

  ```
   =SI(CONTAR.SI($L$4:L4;L4)=1;L4;"")
  ```
- Then enter this in `T14`

  ```
   =SUMA((DIASEM(FILTER(M4:M300;M4:M300<>"");3)>=5)*5+13)
  ```

Or you could just use a simple VBA User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function Bonus(dates As Range) As Long
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim vDates As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim dSum As Long

vDates = dates

Set col = New Collection

'bypass the "key already exists" area
'to create Collection of distinct dates
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each v In vDates
        If v <> "" Then _
            col.Add Item:=v, Key:=CStr(v)
    Next v
    On Error GoTo 0
    
'test for weekend or weekday and sum results
dSum = 0
For Each v In col
    If Weekday(v) = vbSaturday Or Weekday(v) = vbSunday Then
        dSum = dSum + 18
    Else
        dSum = dSum + 13
    End If
Next v

Bonus = dSum
End Function
```

and `T14: =bonus(L4:L300)`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot I have Excel 2019. Sorry about that

Comment: @Kiuden See my edit for some `2019` solutions